# Uploading an attachment from WordPress front-end

Tags: wordpress, frontend, image-uploading

I have a form on the front-end that allows logged-in users to post an event (custom post). My form currently works fine if there is an image attached by the user - however, the image upload field ('postImage') is optional and when an image is not attached, I get a blank screen with no errors (none in the log either). On inspection of the field 'bgc_event_pimg' in  my database I get:

```
O:8:"WP_Error":2:{s:16:"WP_Errorerrors";a:1:{s:12:"upload_error";a:1:{i:0;s:21:"No file was uploaded.";}}s:20:"WP_Errorerror_data";a:0:{}}
```

I think the issue is caused by: ($_FILES[$file]['error']  - instead of ignoring the field/leaving it blank, it is inserting the error but I am unsure of how to handle this accordingly.

```
 if ($_FILES['postImage']) {
   foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
   if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
   }
   $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
   }   
 }
 if ($attach_id > 0){
  update_post_meta($post_id,'bgc_event_pimg',$attach_id);
 }
```

I have the following in functions.php;

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
  return $attach_id;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following -

```
if ($_FILES['postImage']) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       //Add your error action
    } else {
       $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
    }
  }   
}
if ($attach_id > 0){
  update_post_meta($post_id,'bgc_event_pimg',$attach_id);
}
```